# How to Disable IE10 Select Expand Button

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, html-select

I try to disable select html element style (for custom styling) using

```
background:none;
border:none;
outline:none;
```

and everything was right, but not in IE10. I can't hide terrible button with arrow on the right side...

Can anyone help?